# onClick the tab function is not working properly

Tags: jquery

Why when I click on Tab One does the url not working? Please advise.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /* $('.tabs li.current').click(function(){
   alert('asd')
  }); */



  $('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
  })

});

function loadUrl(newLocation) {
  window.location = newLocation;
  return false;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', serif;
  line-height: 1.6
}

.container {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.tabs {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.tabs li {
  background: none;
  color: #222;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.tabs li.current {
  background: #ededed;
  color: #222;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
  background: #ededed;
  padding: 15px;
}

.tab-content.current {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">

  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">
      <a href="javascript:void" onclick="loadUrl('https://www.google.com/'); return false;">
  Tab One</a></li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>

</div>
<!-- container -->
```

Comment: Console says syntax Error :), but it seems to be working as far as tabs is concerned.

Comment: @clearshot66 Do you have the solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you include the JS script in head

[image: step 1]

Second, i don't know if that's the error you were talking about or not but you need to deal with `X-Frame-Options`

[image]

Comment: amended -> https://jsfiddle.net/yingchor/20vnr1p1/

second error is because using the https?

Comment: No. It's because browser protects you from clickjacking. Please read about `X-Frame-Options`.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<a href="javascript:void" onclick="loadUrl('https://www.google.com/'); return false;">
```

To:

```
<a href="void(0)" onclick="return loadUrl('https://www.google.com/')">
```

I don't know why would you do that though :)

Comment: after changes still not working fine, here is the demo https://jsfiddle.net/yingchor/20vnr1p1/1/

Comment: It _is_ working, you just faced next problem in your code, which was not accessible before. Use developer console in your browser -- it clearly and obviously prints you an error.

Comment: The code works fine but you can't test it in a "frame" like code snippet or jsfiddle. I've tested it in Firefox, Chrome and it works.

Comment: @Fian I don't have any errors in my log? please try to test it in your local server or your website.

Comment: It's not happening in your test environment because it uses http and open http or https. But jsfiddle uses https and thus http is restricted. I think possible solution would be using https links for jsfiddle examples.

Comment: No, I've tried that too, actually not in jsfiddle only, in codepen and here as well. they all restrict that.